# filter vs takeWhile: difference and runtime

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, runtime

In GHCI, I have ran the below. The first expression gives the result very fast. The second doesn't (I interrupted it after 10 seconds). I want to understand why? Is there an infinite loop?

```
Prelude> sum (takeWhile (<10000) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..])))
166650
Prelude> sum (filter (<10000) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..])))
Interrupted.
Prelude>
```

Comment: `filter` selects *all* elements in the list that match the condition, wheras `takeWhile` stops from the moment one of the elements fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes there is a huge difference. If we read the documentation, we see:

> [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile)
>
> `takeWhile`, applied to a predicate `p` and a list `xs`, returns the **longest prefix** (possibly empty) of `xs` of elements that satisfy `p`.

whereas:

> [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter)
>
> `filter`, applied to a predicate and a list, returns the **list of those elements that satisfy the predicate**.

As input list for the `filter` and `takeWhile`, you use a list:

```
filter odd (map (^2) [1..])
```

So that means that you generate a list of *all* squares with `map (^2) [1...]`, and then `filter odd` from these. That is again an infinite list (but even if it was limited, that would never terminate, since `filter` has no knowledge about the list, and thus will keep trying to find `odd` elements).

So the input list has infinite size. We can see that the items in the list are growing, but `filter` does not know that. So although after a certain element the list will keep failing, `filter` will keep enumerating over the list when searching for the next element.

`takeWhile` on the other hand terminates from the moment it finds an element that does *not* satisfies the condition. For example:

```
Prelude> takeWhile odd [1,3,5,12,7,9,1,3]
[1,3,5]
```

whereas:

```
Prelude> filter odd [1,3,5,12,7,9,1,3]
[1,3,5,7,9,1,3]
```

Comment: Pretty clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`filter`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:filter) just keeps going through the list you supply to find all elements that satisfy the predicate. Giving it an infinite list it will just keep churning.

[`takeWhile`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) on the other hand returns the longest initial sequence of elements that satisfy the predicate, stopping when one does not.